# Passing dynamic parameter from the url in jnlp file

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a server that runs on the following url.

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

I have JNLP file inside the tomcat folder and hence i can access it by

```
http://localhost:8080/abc.jnlp
```

or by the server ip

```
http://public-ip.org./abc.jnlp
```

Now the problem is i have a file that can be opened with the jnlp file. I want to pass that file as the parameter. So what i did was:

```
@RequestMapping(value="showjnlp",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void showJnlp(){
Process p=RunTime.getRuntime().exec("javaws -open fileName abc.jnlp");
}
```

Now if i do this the file opens in the server computer where the war file hosted. I want to open the file in the client side. Anyone who knows how to open the file that resides in the server that can be passed as the parameter to the client side or be opened in the client side computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you can link up the jnlp as a web page to the client it will download into the client side machine and run there.

Comment: It gets downloaded in the client side machine and i can open it too. Problem is i cannot pass the dynamic parameter. Somewhat like 

    http://localhost:8080/abc.jnlp?args=fileName